# Change button color and sleep for 1 sec java

Tags: java, actionlistener, sleep

How can i change the background of a button to green when i press it , wait for one second and then return to default color background ?
thanks

Comment: I think this is pretty common.. what have you tried..?

Comment: Down-vote from me. I don't like questions that show no degree of prior effort at all.

Comment: "Down-vote from me "Thanks dude !

Answer (score -1):

for answering your question it would be useful to know, which kind of UI library you use? Swing, AWT, whatever?

Try this:

```
final JButton button = new JButton("MyButton");


button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        button.setBackground(Color.green);
        try {
            Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException err) {

        }
        button.setBackground(Color.blue);
    }
});
```

[Sleep 1 second](http://www.java-forums.org/threads-synchronization/528-how-use-sleep-method.html)

Comment: Try that. But this uses the UI thread, so it is blocked in that time. Just create a new thread, if you don't want to block the UI.

@Duncan Let us develop a solution and stop annoying others